# npm install ethereumjs-util on a raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, node.js, javascript

I need to install the npm package ethereumjs-util which will not install on my raspberry pi. I am using a pi 2 with raspbian. The following is the terminal output. Please tell me what I need to do to get a successful install. Thanks for the help.

pi@raspberrypi:~/Transaction $ npm install ethereumjs-util --save npm WARN package.json keypairs@1.0.0 No description npm WARN package.json keypairs@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN package.json keypairs@1.0.0 No README data npm WARN engine ethjs-util@0.1.4: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine keccak@1.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine secp256k1@3.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine strip-hex-prefix@1.0.0: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine is-hex-prefixed@1.0.0: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})

keccak@1.3.0 install /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."
prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.1.2 prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /home/pi/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-cryptocoinjs-keccak-releases-download-v1.3.0-keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/keccak/releases/download/v1.3.0/keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/keccak/releases/download/v1.3.0/keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=0.10.29 runtime=node arch=arm platform=linux) make: Entering directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak/build' CXX(target) Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o In file included from ../src/addon.cc:2:0: ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:326:47: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’ static const unsigned kReplaceInvalidUtf8 = v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8; ^ keccak.target.mk:100: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o' failed make: *** [Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o] Error 1 make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak/build' ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23) gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17) gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12) gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+ gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2 gyp ERR! not ok Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.

npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})

secp256k1@3.3.0 install /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1 prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild || echo "Secp256k1 bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."
prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.1.2 prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /home/pi/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-cryptocoinjs-secp256k1-node-releases-download-v3.3.0-secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node/releases/download/v3.3.0/secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node/releases/download/v3.3.0/secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=0.10.29 runtime=node arch=arm platform=linux) make: Entering directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1/build' CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o In file included from ../src/addon.cc:2:0: ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:326:47: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’ static const unsigned kReplaceInvalidUtf8 = v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8; ^ secp256k1.target.mk:124: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o' failed make: *** [Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o] Error 1 make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1/build' gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23) gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17) gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12) gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+ gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1 gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2 gyp ERR! not ok Secp256k1 bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used. ethereumjs-util@5.1.2 node_modules/ethereumjs-util +-- rlp@2.0.0 +-- bn.js@4.11.6 +-- create-hash@1.1.3 (inherits@2.0.3, cipher-base@1.0.3, ripemd160@2.0.1, sha.js@2.4.8) +-- ethjs-util@0.1.4 (is-hex-prefixed@1.0.0, strip-hex-prefix@1.0.0) +-- keccak@1.3.0 (bindings@1.2.1, inherits@2.0.3, safe-buffer@5.1.0, nan@2.6.2, prebuild-install@2.1.2) +-- secp256k1@3.3.0 (bindings@1.2.1, bip66@1.1.5, safe-buffer@5.1.0, drbg.js@1.0.1, nan@2.6.2, prebuild-install@2.1.2, elliptic@6.4.0) +-- babelify@7.3.0 (object-assign@4.1.1, babel-core@6.25.0) +-- babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1 (babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.23.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs@6.24.1, babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.23.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.23.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.24.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using an older version of node. The important line is this one:

```
ethjs-util@0.1.4: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
```

`ethjs-util` requires at least `npm` 3 and `node` 6.5.0.

## To fix:

1. Remove the older version of `node`:

   ```
   sudo apt purge nodejs
   ```
2. Install a newer version of `node`. There are two ways that you can do this.

   - Install using `nvm`
   - Install using `apt`

   NOTE: If you want to keep node fully updated, you should use `nvm`. If you use `apt` you have to keep adding repositories every time a new major release comes out.

### Install using `nvm`:

- Install `nvm`:
      wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
- Now you can install the latest version of node by running `nvm install node`

### Install using `apt`:

- Add the NodeSource repository

  ```
  sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
  ```
- Install by running `sudo apt install node nodejs npm`

  3. Now run `npm install ethereumjs-util`.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Everything works perfectly now. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Did you use `nvm` or `apt`?

Comment: nvm as you recommended. Your instructions have been imortalized [here](https://gist.github.com/johnshearing/f00d7effd09a80c2f462887778da07a3) for anyone who wants to use a pi to make Ethereum transactions without exposing their private keys to the Internet.